# how to show selected text in a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a static drop-down list control in asp.net page and I have two different string (based on a result which I am fetching through database) now I want to make selected text of the the current input and the indexing and values remains same.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_room_type" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_room_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Type</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Deluxe" Value="2500"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Super Deluxe" Value="3000"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Luxury" Value="5000"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Special Room" Value="10000"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and I have a string Text from Database : lets say Special Room. Now I want that drop-down list i.e, ddl_room_type should automatically bind with the same text and value.

C# Code which I am using:

```
string luxury = "Special Room"; //Value coming form Database
ddl_room_type.SelectedItem.Text = luxury;
```

If I do with this code.. it is just selected the first text as : "Special Room"

Comment: How do you get the value from the database?

Comment: In Which method you are writing this C# code

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you can try this

```
string luxury = "Special Room";
ddl_room_type.ClearSelection();
ddl_room_type.Items.FindByText(luxury).Selected = true;
```

Hope it will be useful

Comment: no its not working . its showing an error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Edited the answer, plz share In Which method you are writing this C# code

Answer (score 0):

Get your values from the database at first for both `Text` and `Value` for loading the `dropdownlist`. So that you don't have to set it once the user makes the selection.